# What can I use in typescript to show a relationship between the values of two interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface baseVal {
    val: string
}

interface parentA{
    checker: baseVal
}

interface parentB{
    someone: baseVal
}

let test = <T extends parentA | parentB>(param: T) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(param) as (keyof T)[]
    keys.forEach(key => {
        let data = param[key] as baseVal // error 

    })
}
```

I'm currently getting an error at "let data = param[key] as baseVal" 
This is what the error states:

> Conversion of type 'T[keyof T]' to type 'baseVal' may be a mistake
>   because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was
>   intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Why does typescript not understand that the values in the interfaces are both the same type? 
How can I create the interfaces so that typescript is aware of this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what happens when you have type parentA | parentB is a type with no keys at all, because union (pipe) does not behave as you would expect in the case of interfaces. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types:

> If a value has the type A | B, we only know for certain that it has members that both A and B have. In this example, Bird has a member named fly. We can’t be sure whether a variable typed as Bird | Fish has a fly method. If the variable is really a Fish at runtime, then calling pet.fly() will fail

You can verify this for yourself by putting in a line `let x = param.someone.val;`. You'll see the intellisense complain that `param` does not have a member `someone`. That's because `param` *might* be of type parentA, in which case that line would throw an exception at runtime because `param.someone` is undefined. So in short you cannot use a union type here.

One of the main purposes of typescript is to prevent runtime errors due to incorrect typing, so if an object passed to a function may be one of two types, you cannot access a field belonging to just one of those types. In some cases, you can use type checking as described on the linked page in this situation, but in your case, the problem is not so easily solved. Notice that you iterate over the keys of `param`. Imagine if the types had more than one key. How would typescript resolve the type of param[key]? In the provided code, a person can see what the type is, but in general, this approach is not valid. Therefore, if you want to keep the code roughly as you have it, you may need to go with something like:

```
interface baseVal {
    val: string
}

interface parentA{
    checker: baseVal;
}

interface parentB{
    someone: baseVal;
}

interface parent {
  [key: string]: baseVal;
}

let test = <T extends parent>(param: T) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(param) as (keyof T)[]
    keys.forEach(key => {
        let data = param[key] as baseVal; 
    })
}
```

(Note that this would not be suitable if your actual types have more keys with different types, but then your code would be invalid anyway.)

Comment: I understand. Its just weird that typescript doesn't allow Object.keys to return keyof T.. It's as if dynamic operations aren't really typescripts strong point. I'm saying this with only two weeks of experience working with TS but I'd think Object. [keys, entries,values] would be properly typed

Comment: But the value associated with keyof T is not a single type and that's the problem. You need to consider the possibility of parentA and parentB having more than one key, with each key associated with a different type of value. Then when you iterate over the keys, what is the type of param[key]?